# Run sequence of commands in anaconda prompt from a batch file

Tags: batch-file, anaconda, command-prompt, jupyter-lab

I want to run a sequence of commands in anaconda prompt, namely:

`activate islp` - to activate the library environment set up in Anaconda Navigator
`cd C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Desktop\Coding project` - to change directory to my coding project
`jupyter lab` - to open Jupyter lab.

Based on the below article:
https://medium.com/@roddyjaques/how-to-run-anaconda-programs-with-a-bat-file-5f6dd7675508

I created a .bat file:

```
call "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\condabin\activate.bat"
activate islp
cd "C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Desktop\Coding project"
jupyter lab
pause
```

and I can see the anaconda prompt opening briefly, however it closes without opening the Jupyter Lab app in the browser.

Also the `pause` command does not leave the anaconda prompt window open, as it is desribed in the article.

Is the syntax in the file incorrect?
If there is a different solution other than a batch file I'm also fine with it, I just want to execute changing the environment, changing the directory and starting up Jupyter lab with one action.

Comment: Would you not use `conda activate islp`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that the `activate islp` command line did not have the `call` command in front of it, and so the batch processing was never returned to the initial batch file. The working script is as follows:

```
call "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\condabin\activate.bat"
call activate islp
cd "C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Desktop\Coding project"
jupyter lab
```